# Entanglement question

Tags: quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

If photons A and B are entangled and A shows, say, spin up, then B will show spin down. My question is, can a researcher change the spin of A, say by putting it through some kind of filter? If so, does B automatically change?

Comment: No, if you touch A you destroy the entanglement.

Comment: The spin of the photon is forwards or backward depending on the circular polarization.

Comment: @JahanClaes:  "If you touch A you destroy the entanglement" is certainly false.  If the particles are in an entangled state $A\otimes B+C\otimes D$ and if you "touch" the first particle by applying the unitary operator $U$, they will enter the state $U(A)\otimes B+U(C)\otimes D$, which is, in general, entangled.

Comment: "If A shows, say, spin up, then B will show spin down".  Maybe, maybe not, depending on what measurements you're making.

Comment: you measure what it is not what you want to.

Comment: @WillO It depends on what you mean by "touch". If you mean "apply the unitary operator $U$", then indeed the entanglement is preserved. But if you mean "measure," as the OP said, then under the Copenhagen interpretation, the system is non-unitarily projected into an eigenstate of the measured quantity, and the entanglement is indeed destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't "choose what to measure." The measurement outcome probabilities are fully determined by the prior state of the particle via the Born rule. You also can't use a local Hamiltonian acting on one half of the system to time-evolve the joint quantum state via the Schrodinger equation in a way that affects local observables in the other half of the system. This is the "no communication theorem," and it's what prevents you from using entanglement for faster-than-light communication (or slower-than-light communication, for that matter).

Comment: If touching A destroys the entanglement, I don't understand why there's spooky action at a distance. Couldn't both particles have been programmed to respond to the same type of measurement in the same way?

Comment: @Fred For one particular choice of commuting observables, yes; for all *possible* observables, no, because being in a definite state of one observable automatically precludes being in a definite state of certain other, non-commuting observables, and Bell's theorem shows that there's no possible "preprogramming" (either deterministic or classically stochastic) that generates the Born statistics.